# autoAdjustmentFilters for CIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, filter, core-image

Following is the code for autoAdjustmentFilters provided in apple development videos. But it is giving me one warning and one error. Any body can help me..
[image]

Comment: For one thing, Objective-C is case sensitive. You have an extra capital 'M' in that constant.

Comment: Looking at this again, I don't know where you pulled that constant from, but the constant name you want is `kCIInputImageKey`, not `kCIImageInputImage`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067998/cifilter-with-uislider

Comment: I used that constant from apple development video for core image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put in @"inputImage" instead of the constant. Should work fine.

Comment: which constant to replace with @"inputImage" ?

Comment: Instead of kCIImageInputImage, put @"inputImage".

Comment: as Brad Larson commented, the constant is kCIInputImageKey